# Why does this jQuery .css() not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, centering

I have this javascript to center a `span` in a `div`:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var positionLeft = (winWidth/2) - 62;
var positionTop = (winHeight/2) - 32;

$('#centerMessage').ccs("position","absolute");
$('#centerMessage').ccs("top",positionTop);
$('#centerMessage').ccs("left",positionLeft);
```

I keep getting the error that the object does not have the method css. Any idea what is wrong?

All the HTML and CSS are at this fiddle (I am getting the exact same error there: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/s6WQD/

Comment: ccs? thats not right...

Comment: @cthom06 O, wow thanks. I am not very smart.

Comment: When the console complains that a method doesn't exist... it usually doesn't ;)

Comment: $.fn.ccs = $.fn.css. :-)

Comment: Nice comment, chromedude. That made me laugh!

Comment: @Box9 yeah, usually that is true the problem is that I was apparently blind.

Comment: Hey, it happens to the best of us. :) The bug is between the ears, so to speak.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Yeah, its just that it bugs for the next hour as you think you just spent 15 minutes trying to figure out a typing error.

Comment: @chromedude - I spent all morning once trying to figure out what turned out to be the [trailing comma of death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/). This is before it was well-known. You want to talk about frustrated! I literally was a wreck before I figured it out, then spent all afternoon pissed alternately at IE and myself for both of us being so stupid.

Comment: I still twitch a little when I think about it.

Comment: @Jared Farrish That's pretty brutal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using ccs not css in your code

```
$('#centerMessage').css("position","absolute");
$('#centerMessage').css("top",positionTop + 'px');  // add unit also
$('#centerMessage').css("left",positionLeft + 'px');
```

Answer (score 4):

You should add units to your values, as well:

```
$('#centerMessage').css("top",positionTop + "px");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using `.css`, not `.ccs`

Answer (score 3):

you sure you have jquery included into your page ?

```
.ccs => .css
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#centerMessage').css("top",positionTop + "px");
$('#centerMessage').css("left",positionLeft + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

misspelled the property:

```
.ccs - > .css
```